# How to compile ffmpeg via Alchemy gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, adobe, ffmpeg, alchemy

So I created ffmpeg configuration file that makes it pure C (platform independent, but only theoretically)

So my config is simple (0.6.1,0.6.3 tested):

```
./configure  --disable-doc  --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe  --disable-ffserver    --disable-avdevice   --disable-avfilter   --disable-pthreads  --disable-everything --enable-muxer=flv --enable-encoder=flv --enable-encoder=h263  --disable-mmx  --disable-shared   --prefix=bin/  --disable-protocols --disable-network --disable-optimizations --disable-debug  --disable-asm --disable-stripping
```

Compiling this on Linux will resolve in 4 libs with totall size of 1 mb.

But I need to compile ffmpeg with custom compiler (opensource gcc analog called [Adobe Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/), lets us compile C/c++ into Flash)

It gives me errors on nearly each and every file during standart Make:

```
Array @ARGV missing the @ in argument 1 of shift() at /home/rupert/Downloads/alchemy-ubuntu-v0.5a/achacks/gcc line 218.
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wtype-limits"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fno-signed-zeros"
```

So what shall I do - how to compile ffmpeg (at least smallest part of it) via alchemy?

***Update***
If we would fix that errors manually (2 in configure.mak and one in alchemy gcc) we would get a really messy and long output like:

```
> $ make -w install

make: Entering directory `/home/rupert/Downloads/ffmpeg-0.6.1'
AR  libavformat/libavformat.a
llvm-ld: error opening 'avformat/libavformat.l.bc' for writing!
llvm-ranlib: Archive file does not exist
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.a
install: cannot stat `libavformat/libavformat.a': No such file or directory
llvm-ranlib: Archive file does not exist
AR  libavcodec/libavcodec.a
llvm-ld: error opening 'avcodec/libavcodec.l.bc' for writing!
llvm-ranlib: Archive file does not exist
INSTALL libavcodec/libavcodec.a
install: cannot stat `libavcodec/libavcodec.a': No such file or directory
llvm-ranlib: Archive file does not exist
AR  libswscale/libswscale.a
llvm-ld: error opening 'swscale/libswscale.l.bc' for writing!
llvm-ranlib: Archive file does not exist
INSTALL libswscale/libswscale.a
install: cannot stat `libswscale/libswscale.a': No such file or directory
llvm-ranlib: Archive file does not exist
AR  libavutil/libavutil.a
llvm-ld: error opening 'avutil/libavutil.l.bc' for writing!
llvm-ranlib: Archive file does not exist
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.a
install: cannot stat `libavutil/libavutil.a': No such file or directory
llvm-ranlib: Archive file does not exist
INSTALL libavformat/avformat.h
INSTALL libavformat/avio.h
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.pc
INSTALL libavcodec/avcodec.h
INSTALL libavcodec/avfft.h
INSTALL libavcodec/dxva2.h
INSTALL libavcodec/opt.h
INSTALL libavcodec/vaapi.h
INSTALL libavcodec/vdpau.h
INSTALL libavcodec/xvmc.h
INSTALL libavcodec/libavcodec.pc
INSTALL libswscale/swscale.h
INSTALL libswscale/libswscale.pc
INSTALL libavutil/adler32.h
INSTALL libavutil/attributes.h
INSTALL libavutil/avstring.h
INSTALL libavutil/avutil.h
INSTALL libavutil/base64.h
INSTALL libavutil/common.h
INSTALL libavutil/crc.h
INSTALL libavutil/error.h
INSTALL libavutil/fifo.h
INSTALL libavutil/intfloat_readwrite.h
INSTALL libavutil/log.h
INSTALL libavutil/lzo.h
INSTALL libavutil/mathematics.h
INSTALL libavutil/md5.h
INSTALL libavutil/mem.h
INSTALL libavutil/pixdesc.h
INSTALL libavutil/pixfmt.h
INSTALL libavutil/rational.h
INSTALL libavutil/sha1.h
INSTALL libavutil/avconfig.h
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.pc
LD  ffmpeg_g
WARNING: While resolving call to function 'main' arguments were dropped!
Cannot yet select: 0x8e707e8: i32 = ConstantPool < i64 6881500230622117888> 0
llc[0x86c7dec]
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 6
make: Leaving directory `/home/rupert/Downloads/ffmpeg-0.6.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

FlasCC(Alchemy 2) does compile ffmpeg fine - for anyone who is trying, basically you need to download ffmpeg source. Go to ffmpeg directory, do

```
PATH=/cygdrive/c/PATH_TO_FLASCC/sdk/usr/bin:$PATH ./configure --prefix=/cygdrive/c/PATH_TO_FLASCC/sdk/usr
```

Now it's good if you run configure with some restrictions so it doesn't include every codec or filter there is(takes ages). Additional configure params from my use case:

```
--disable-ffserver --disable-everything --enable-filter=scale --enable-demuxer=flv --enable-muxer=ogg --enable-protocol=file --disable-network --disable-debug --disable-yasm --disable-asm --disable-stripping --enable-memalign-hack --disable-shared --enable-decoder=flashsv --enable-encoder=mpeg1video --enable-encoder=libtheora --enable-encoder=libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis
```

Important is to `--disable-everything` and then enable only what you need.

Then run `./make` and `./make` install   (with the PATH in front of those commands), it should produce and install ffmpeg libs.

When I built a test swf, all seemed to work. I've used their (modified) sample where they encode 25 dummy mpeg frames. I'm tracing the encoding progress at least and seeing the frames being encoded.

SWC is a problem though, if you would want to use that. I'm getting strange errors - first it couldn't find codec(got NULL when using the find codec function), when I specified it by name, it can't allocate codec context(also got NULL). Then I compiled it in pure Flex and it got over this one, but couldn't open the codec (basically all of those are av_ something library functions). I really don't understand why SWC doesn't work with these as with emit-swf all works perfectly fine.

Maybe someone could enlighten on the SWC / SWF differences.

Answer (score 0):

There was some discussion about this on the Adobe Forums [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1004051).  It seems rather involved, though some folks seem to have made some progress.

Comment: So... I see some of them came to situation close to mine (actually I was looking all day long onto that post..)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the new flash c compiler [Adobe Flash cc](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/flascc/). I hope it may help you to compile ffmpeg in flash.