# Adobe alchemy compiler problem- it generates .l.bc files, how to turn them into swc's?

Tags: c, actionscript-3, gcc, compiler-construction, ffmpeg

So I try to compile ffmpeg as I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317816/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-via-alchemy-gcc) after [this](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/25449?tstart=0) patch I started seeing .l.bc files but no .swc files. So how to use alchemy completion suite to turn .l.bc into .swc?

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to use the -swc option?

```
gcc myMainClass.c -O3 -Wall -swc -o mySwcFile.swc
```

Are you sure there are no c++ libraries it depends on? Should you be using g++?

```
g++ myMainClass.c -O3 -Wall -swc -o mySwcFile.swc
```

Are you using your own ashacks (AS3.h) enabled main class (glue class)? You can't just throw any c/c++ class into alchemy and expect it to work, you have to define an [interface](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aDocumentation%3aDeveloping_with_Alchemy%3aC_API) between the c/c++ code and flash.

Is the gcc/g++ throwing any errors in the output? If there is just one error, a swc will not be created.

Are you sure you're running with [alc-on](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aDocumentation%3aGetting_Started)?

Sorry if these troubleshooting steps are too basic, all I can think of.